# How is INVOCATION scoped property set in mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm new to Mule, while i was running my Mule application, i am setting a value to 'op' from query parameters. Later i'm using the same to determine which option in 'choice' to be executed. Somehow i see each time value is set as 'div' and in logs i find that it is due to Invocation scoped property (I guess).

Can someone help me out here, Below is the log and beneath it is the xml.

```
INVOCATION scoped properties:
    **op**=div
    var1=12
    var2=3
  INBOUND scoped properties:
    accept=*/*
    accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch
    accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8
    cache-control=no-cache
    connection=keep-alive
    host=localhost:8081
    http.listener.path=/samples
    http.method=GET
    http.query.params=ParameterMap{[**op**=[sub], a=[12], b=[3]]}
    http.query.string=**op**=sub&a=12&b=3
    http.relative.path=/samples
    http.remote.address=/127.0.0.1:8503
    http.request.path=/samples
    http.request.uri=/samples?op=sub&a=12&b=3
    http.scheme=http
    http.uri.params=ParameterMap{[]}
    http.version=HTTP/1.1
    postman-token=8cfdd0be-5204-1d8a-9b0e-c829c7ddeb9e
    user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
  SESSION scoped properties:
```

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="mudb.mulesoft-training.com" port="3306" user="mule" password="mule" database="training" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <sub-flow name="sub_expression">
        <expression-component doc:name="sub exp"><![CDATA[import java.lang.Double;

double firstValue = flowVars.var1;
double secondValue = flowVars.var2;
double result =  (firstValue) - (secondValue);
payload =  result]]></expression-component>
        <set-payload value="Result is: #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="Multiplication_expression">
        <expression-component doc:name="mul Exp"><![CDATA[import java.lang.Double;

double firstValue = flowVars.var1;
double secondValue = flowVars.var2;
double result =  (firstValue) * (secondValue);
payload =  result]]></expression-component>
        <set-payload value="Result is: #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="Div_expression">
        <expression-component doc:name="Div Exp"><![CDATA[import java.lang.Double;

double firstValue = flowVars.var1;
double secondValue = flowVars.var2;
double result =  (firstValue) / (secondValue);
payload =  result]]></expression-component>
        <set-payload value="Result is: #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="Set_Flow_Variables">
        <set-variable variableName="var1" value="#[message.inboundProperties.get('http.query.params').get('a')]" metadata:id="8354c885-e13c-4ed8-be46-38e65107898f" doc:name="Variable1"/>
        <set-variable variableName="var2" value="#[message.inboundProperties.get('http.query.params').get('b')]" metadata:id="d18ef85a-f8d6-4a0b-9076-159ff9b51bca" doc:name="Variable2"/>
        <set-variable variableName="op" value="#[message.inboundProperties.get('http.query.params').get('op')] " metadata:id="22fd48bf-7d8c-4b09-a0a3-60f4a7ccbd89" doc:name="Variable"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="Choice">
        <choice tracking:enable-default-events="true" doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.op = 'div']">
                <flow-ref name="Div_expression" doc:name="Div_expression"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars.op = 'mul']">
                <flow-ref name="Multiplication_expression" doc:name="Multiplication_expression"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars.op = 'sub']">
                <flow-ref name="sub_expression" doc:name="sub_expression"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-payload value="invalid operator" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </sub-flow>
    <flow name="sampleprojectFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/samples" allowedMethods="GET,POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <flow-ref name="Set_Flow_Variables" doc:name="Set_Flow_Variables"/>
        <flow-ref name="Choice" doc:name="Choice"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the **equality** operator. Incorrectly, you put the **assignment** instead.

- Issue: `#[flowVars.op = 'div']`
- Solution: `#[flowVars.op == 'div']`